# Retrieving the coordinates of the MySQL point type

Tags: mysql

I'm storing lat/long pairs in MySQL as a point using something like:

```
GeomFromText('POINT(32 -122)')
```

Given the point, how do i retrieve the individual X/Y coordinates?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Let's say you store `GeomFromText('POINT(32 -122)')` as a column called `MY_POINT` in a table called `MY_TABLE`.

Getting the `X` coordinate (will return `32` in this example):

```sql
SELECT ST_X(MY_POINT) as longitude FROM MY_TABLE;
```

Getting the `Y` coordinate (will return `-122` in this example):

```sql
SELECT ST_Y(MY_POINT) as latitude FROM MY_TABLE;
```

**Important**: Prior to version 5.6, use X() and Y() instead of ST_X() and ST_Y().

Comment: @AbhishekBorar I've updated the answer to correct for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you store `GeomFromText('POINT(32 -122)')` as a column called `MY_POINT` in a table called `MY_TABLE`.
There are several ways to get the point data.

- First Check MySQL version

  `SELECT VERSION()`
- For MySQL 5.6 or older version using

  `SELECT X(MY_POINT) AS Latitude, Y(MY_POINT) AS Longitude FROM MY_TABLE`
- For MySQL 5.7 version using, although previous command also recognized.

  `SELECT ST_X(MY_POINT) AS Latitude, ST_Y(MY_POINT) AS Longitude FROM MY_TABLE`
- For MySQL 8.0 version using, although previous command also recognized. The main difference is this command for Point objects that have a geographic spatial reference system (SRS).

  `SELECT ST_Latitude(MY_POINT) AS Latitude, ST_Longitude(MY_POINT) AS Longitude FROM MY_TABLE`

Hope this would helps.