# How can I handle a MySQL POINT() field in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table with a POINT field to storage GPS data (longitude and latitude) but I can't handle it in PHP.

```
$query = "SELECT COORDS FROM PHOTOS";
$result = mysqli_query($db_conn, $query);
mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $result['COORDS'];
```

This way I just get a weird string.

I've used AsText in MySQL console and it gives me a WKT with the coords, but I'd like to catch it in PHP.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT AsText(COORDS) FROM PHOTOS";
```

But my question would be how can I access through PHP to that field?

(I've also heard about unpack() function in PHP but it throws me warnings)

Comment: Would the method in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239180/retrieving-the-coordinates-of-the-mysql-point-type/6239219 do it?

Comment: The problem is that I need to handle it in PHP. Your suggestion just explain the query in MySQL.

Comment: So returning 2 values (x & y) from a query can't be used in PHP?

Comment: Sorry. There upside I posted the way I get the fields. I exec the query and it gives me an array with the fields. In this case, $result gives me a key called `['AsText(COORDS)']` which, as you might guess, has any value.

Comment: What do you mean by “any value”? That query will return the WKT. If you have a problem with the result name you can always alias it with `as`

Comment: I mean there's no value. It's NULL. But anyways, do you think the name's key would be `['AsText(COORDS)']` insted of `['COORDS']`? Edit: I tried with alias but is still NULL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have stored  in db a geometry starting from text e GeomFromText('POINT(25 -118)') 
in a column  named  MY_POINT

You can easly get the X, Y coords of you point using

```
SELECT ST_X(MY_POINT) as latitude,  ST_Y(MY_POINT) as longitude  FROM MY_TABLE;
```

the in php  you can  access to the value using latitude  and longitude as column  index  in your array of coords

```
SELECT ST_X(COORDS) as latitude,  ST_Y(COORDS) as longitude  FROM MY_TABLE;
```

Comment: Sombody suggested me using alias but I tried them in a no-sense way. Thanks for taking the time to explain. It worked.