# Get point data type from blob MySql

Tags: python, mysql, geometry, shapely

MySQL table I am using looks like:

```
   id       count        point
0   1       1864         BLOB
1   2       6466         BLOB
2   3       4652         BLOB
```

describe table_name; 
tells me that point has datatype "point"

So I usually extract its latitude and longitude coordinate by using

```
select 
  id,
  count,
  ST_AsText(point) as point
from table_name
```

correctly rendering

```
   id       count        point
0   1       1864         POINT (117.036077 77.490958)
1   2       6466         POINT (157.03103 87.491231)
2   3       4652         POINT (147.030428 17.4925)
```

However when I move this table into python dataframe to use it is returned as a string 
ex: "POINT (117.036077 77.490958)"

I want to keep them as point object or convert string version into Points object from

Shapely :https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html

right now I am doing:

```
query = """
select 
  id,
  count,
  ST_AsText(point) as point
from table_name
"""
df = pd.read_sql(query, con=conn)
df["lng"] = df.geocode.apply(lambda row: str(row).split()[0][6:])
df["lat"] = df.geocode.apply(lambda row: str(row).split()[1][:-1])
df = df.astype({"lng": float, "lat":float})

from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
df["pt"] = df[['lng', 'lat']].apply(Point, axis=1)
```

which is tedious. I want to convert to Point object straight from MySQL Point datatype.

I want to do this so I can simplify code below by creating a polygon with those boundaries and see if point is inside a polygon in which shapely library is used.

```
df = df.loc[(129.569968 <= df.lng)&
            (df.lng <= 130.163217)& 
            (37.425664 <= df.lat) &
            (df.lat<= 37.668981)]
```

Note: I don't usually import library inline, it is just for easy readability

If anything is unclear let me know, thanks in advance!

Comment: did you look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239180/retrieving-the-coordinates-of-the-mysql-point-type. You could extract the lat and lon directly using your SQL string.

Comment: Thanks, I think it is more efficient than my method. What to do when problem solved?

Comment: @makewhite You can close your question as a duplicate of the one that I linked.